# how to get listview data for a selected user for a specific value?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

how to get listview data for selected user for specific value android.
i have list view containing users.I want to select user to get its name and phone from Arraylist that contained.above code tells how i got data in lists result and data.below code about getting data from lists.but it shows same phone number for every selected user.I want to do this:
[image]

```
    final Query query = mRef.orderByChild("blood_Group").equalTo(bloodgrp);

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {

                User value = child.getValue(User.class);

                if(value.equals(city)){


                    data.add(value);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(Searchview.this,"Donors not found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



above code tells how i got data in lists result and data.below code about getting data from lists.but it shows same phone number for every selected user.

    //List Listener

    listResult.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {


           User user = adapter.getItem(position);
            String name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);



            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Searchview.this);


            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_details);
            dialog.setTitle("Call Donor");

            //adding text dynamically

            TextView t1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
            TextView t2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtBldtype);
            TextView t3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
            TextView t4 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtcity);

            t1.setText(name);
            t2.setText(bloodgrp);
            t3.setText(phone);
            t4.setText(city);
```

now new error is:
  [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFxYG.png)

Comment: selected user means ? can you more elaborate it ?

Comment: please clear your question

Comment: from selected item means selected user

Comment: Assuming the source of the ListView is an ArrayList of Donors called **myDonors**, then you access the Donor object using `myDonor.get(position)`, assuming that you have a `getUser` method, and that method returns a string, then you could use `String this_user = myDonor.get(position).getuser();`

Comment: i dont have idea.. please suggest somethin

Comment: no getUser method

Comment: Am I supposed to magically know what methods you have? Adapt what I have said for your situation.

Comment: only pojo classes

Comment: thanks! it solved name but how to get phone no.

Comment: i did not use custom adapter.   
i have used String name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
     
it returns object.

Comment: still no answer

Comment: ok so what adapter are you using? `ArrayAdapter`? if so, how it is created? what is used as `T` in `ArrayAdapter<T>`?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);   String is used as <T>

Comment: then try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/CVZNJN07)

Comment: I have used register model class to set values and set the object to firebase.Now what should i do to retrieve the values, means Now creating another model class named User and then???

Comment: Now i have understanding what do you want to say! If i am wrong correct me.Instead of adding values in ArrayList directly add to adapter using user object.?????

Comment: you can use `ArrayList` too, see all `ArrayAdapter` constructors - there is one that takes `T[] objects` and one that takes `List<T> objects`

Comment: Why user class has no getter setter??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone finally solved by achieving this.

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                User value = child.getValue(User.class);

                if(value.getCity().equals(city)){


                    data.add(value);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                }
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```